# Setting up MC with dedicated db

Tags: marketing-cloud, database

We have a new MC account we would like to start setting up. We have purchased a dedicated db sku for this account.

Are there any implactions or things we should know while setting up this new MC account? We couldn't find any mention of using dedciated db in the MC set up documentation.

Thanks,

Barak

Comment: Why did you purchase a dedicated database? Was this to facilitate Field Level Encryption or some other feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dedicated DB is entirely transparent, from the application perspective. There are no precautions to take, and everything is to be configured equally as if you were located as a tenant on a shared DB.

In a dedicated DB, you will have performance improvements over a shared DB, especially when it comes to the number of contacts you can inject into Journey Builder. But again, this is only evident in extreme cases, where you try to inject millions of contacts every hour.